# Automate functional testing for WCF services

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, test-strategy

I'm trying to develop a tool to automate `functional testing` of `WCF` web services.

I have researched a lot on previous projects and developments to start, but I did not find any valid resource to start.

I have used `Soap UI` tool open source, but it does not allow to test using form as it is available in `pro` version.

I'm using `.NET framework` and `C#` language to develop this tool so that if we enter the `WSDL URL` we can able to test the service and save the case for regression testing later.

Comment: Welcome to SQA, Sraven. I'm having trouble understanding your question. More accurately, I don't see a question.

Comment: I haven't used the form based input from SoapUI pro (I have only used the free version) but it seems like for manual testing purposes you can use tools such as Fiddler, or browser plug-ins such as Postman.

Comment: Hello corsiKa I used the soapUI where it allows us to give the input for functional testing of a wcf service where we can just enter the input for a service and see the expected output. So I am trying to develop the same tool which allows to save a particular case and will help in regression testing later

Comment: Would you consider Excel as a good enough GUI to capture your test cases?

Comment: What's the advantage of having a form to enter data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in a pinch, I've done some testing with Microsoft's [WcfTestClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx).  It will build out a barebones gui for you based on the service meta-data.  Another option that I've seen recommended often, but never tried myself, is [wcfstorm](http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/default.aspx).

Sam is right though, depending on how complex the requests are, good options can be [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), [WFetch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/284285), and the like.

In the end, if you want to be able to save the test case for later, maybe modify it etc, you'd probably be best off to roll together an automated test suite.

Comment: Thank you Lyndon I was actually looking for a tool like this one WcfStorm is best for functional testing and it allows to save a test case for future testing with a click of a button it is almost 100% automation and due to licensing I need to built it on my own now with the same functionality provided by wcfStorm Functional Testing.

Comment: Only Enterprise Edition allows us have the extra features I wish Microsoft should have provided along with the vs for the test automation for Wcf Services.